# Meta description tag

Tags: html, meta-tags

Can someone tell me why google is not showing my description?Below is  the meta tag from my header.That's not the best description but you got the idea.

```
<meta name="Description" content="Best color Palettes and Fonts to improve the look and feel of your application."/>
```

Instead of this description it shows all the text from the page as a description.Don't tell me it takes time for Google to update.My description is there for nearly 2 months.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. SEO is off-topic.

Comment: I know that.I just thought I had something wrong in my html code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Google's algorithms have determined that showing the text from the page is better for Google's users than the meta description you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

Description is only used if Google deems it's a better text than what it can find on the page in connection with the users search.